# AutoComplete gives red warning when value is set to the useState that it modifies

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

```
        const [country, set_country] = useState();

        <Autocomplete
          autoHighlight={true} //needed
          autoSelect={true}
          id="geo-select-country"
          options={all_country}
          value={country} // culprit that causes red warning
          onChange={(event, selected_country) => {
            set_country(selected_country);
          }}
          classes={autocomplete_classes}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} label={"Country"} margin="none" focused />
          )}
        />
```

warning message:

```
index.js:1 MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Autocomplete to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Autocomplete element for the lifetime of the component.
The nature of the state is determined during the first render. It's considered controlled if the value is not `undefined`.
```

The AutoComplete modifies the `useState`, but the value of the `useState` modifies the `AutoComplete`.

Is this not correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because your country value is `undefined` in first render, Just provide initial value for your country state, like this:

```
const [country, set_country] = React.useState('');
```

or

```
const [country, set_country] = React.useState(null);
```

When you don't provide `value` attribute on `AutoComplete` or when you set `value` attribute with `undefined`, MaterialUI considers `AutoComplete` as uncontrolled component, it means that actually MaterialUI considers you haven't provide any state by yourself to update the `value` of `AutoComplete`, but if you provide `value` on `AutoComplete`, materialUI considers `AutoComplete` as controlled component, it means that materialUI knows that you have defined some state value to controll the value of `AutoComplete`.

In your example, in the first render your `country` is `undefined`, so MaterialUI considers `AutoComplete` as uncotrolled component, and tries to controll the value of `AutoComplete` by ownself, but in the next renders, your country is not `undefined`, so material has to change some inner decisions and this cause the warning it throws.

Comment: thanks again. Do you mind, in your answer, also explain why?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer and hope it could be clarify the issue